# Strange && operator behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 3.2.13, I expected the following line to return true or false, but when `href` is nil, `hasHref` is set to nil:

```
hasHref = (defined?(href) && !href.blank?)
```

I know how to fix this, but was curious why this wasn't working how I expected. It worked as I had expected in Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo && bar` does not return `true` or `false`. It returns `foo` when `foo` is **not** *trueish* and `bar` when `foo` was *trueish*. Definition of *trueish*: Not `nil` or `false`.

`defined?` never returns `true` or `false`, it returns a type description. When `href` is not defined then `defined?(href)` returns `nil` (what is not *trueish*), therefore `nil` is returned.

If you really need `true` or `false` change your code to:

```
hasHref = !!(defined?(href) && !href.blank?)
```

For possible return values of `defined?` see: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UG

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive that `defined` returns the definition of the variable instead of a boolean as its name suggests. I just ended up doing `hasHref = (defined?(href) != nil && !href.blank?)`. Thanks for the explanation.